# SQL Server Triggers: How can I obtain a value used in the query string in my trigger's where clause?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I need to create a trigger in SQL Server which is **conditionally** fired when a user attempts to **delete** a row in the table.

I have 2 tables in the database `Airlines`:

- `Passenger` - it has information on passengers. I need to create trigger on this table, obviously
- `Record` - it records the flight(s) a passenger has been on

My trigger should work as follows:

If a passenger has never been on a flight, it should be deleted if attempted.
But if he/she has **NOT** been on a flight, it should restrict the action and print the number of times he has been on any flight.

The only thing (I hope) I am struggling with is:

How would I specify any `WHERE` clause inside a query in the trigger if I do not know which particular passenger I need to look for until a user attempts to delete it?

So, **long story short:** is there any way to obtain a value passed in a query's `WHERE` clause to be used in a trigger?

Thank you very much for your time!

Here is my code:

```
ALTER TRIGGER Restrict_Delete 
ON Records
INSTEAD OF DELETE 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @r_count INT

    SET @r_count = (SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(*) 
                    FROM Passenger P, Records R 
                    WHERE P.passenger_id = R.passenger_id 
                      AND P.passenger_id = ???)

    IF @r_count > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        PRINT ('Permission denied. ' + CAST (@r_count AS Varchar(3)) + ' record(s) exist.') 
    END
    ELSE 
        PRINT 'No records exist. Record deleted!'
    END
```

How do I determine the passenger_id in my query?

Comment: Is this homework? The best way of preventing orphaned flight records would be a foreign key not a trigger.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `deleted` and `inserted` tables!

These are special tables that exist in triggers and contain records copied from the actual tables.  When you change a row in a table, a copy of the old row goes into the `deleted` table, and a copy of the new row goes into the `inserted` table.  Since you're just deleting, you only need to use the `deleted` table.

Here's how the SQL could look inside your trigger:

```
DECLARE @r_count INT
SET @r_count = Count(*) 
FROM   Records R  -- You don't actually need the Passenger table for this.
WHERE  r.Passenger_id IN (
        select  d.Passenger_id
        from    Deleted d
    )
IF @r_count > 0
BEGIN
        Rollback Tran
        PRINT ('Permission denied. ' + CAST (@r_count AS Varchar(3)) + ' record(s) exist.') 
END
ELSE 
        PRINT 'No records exist. Record deleted!'
```

Something you need to be aware of, though:  a trigger is called once per statement, not once per record.  So if you delete two passengers with one DELETE statement, you'll get only one trigger call.  The logic you had (and I adapted) will check for *any* record that was deleted by that DELETE statement.  You could get quite a large number for `@r_count` if you're doing a bulk delete!

If you need to code around that, try to avoid using a cursor actually in your trigger:  it will make deletes very slow.

Also, be aware that the `PRINT` statement will appear in SSMS and can be retrieved in ADO.NET with a bit of fiddling around, but doesn't appear in traces or get returned as part of a recordset.  If you need to log this failure, you're going to need to write to a database table.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking time to answer my query.
So, what if a user attempts to delete 2 passengers at once and only 1 of those 2 passengers meets the condition specified in the trigger?
I assume that will cause deletion of both passengers since @r_count will be greater than 0?

Comment: That is correct.  As Martin Smith points out in his comment, if your intention is to prevent deleting passengers that have existing flights, you'd get this behavior automatically if you implemented a foreign key.  There isn't much real-world advantage to using a trigger to do it.  If you need to log the records that can't be deleted, you can determine that with a query before deleting.